# DjangoRelatedObjectDoesNotExist at /profile/

Tags: python, django, signals, profile, create-view

I've been through in similar topics for days for a possible solution, however none of them solved my issue which seems pretty simple to me but I stucked on this error right after I created a user: RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at /profile/
[Error I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6YMkJ.png)

I know there must be something missing in my singlas.py which does not create the Profile after creation of a User but I'm lost in solutions after tried many. Any help will make my day after long frustration period;

In project main folder; settings.py

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '7aa*ng4p*o!9h4%hyfgu=9xy69aumg6hzbz3g)1mf^4!+gi+e0'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

# Application definition

DEFAULT_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'apps.daily_brief',
    'apps.users',
    'apps.crm',
]

THIRD_PARTY_APPS = [
    'crispy_forms',
    'django_cleanup',
    'social_django',
]

LOCAL_APPS = []

INSTALLED_APPS = DEFAULT_APPS + THIRD_PARTY_APPS + LOCAL_APPS

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'social_django.middleware.SocialAuthExceptionMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'project_folder.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR + '/templates/',],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',

                'social_django.context_processors.backends', 
                'social_django.context_processors.login_redirect',
            ],
        },
    },
]

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
            'social_core.backends.facebook.FacebookOAuth2',
            'social_core.backends.twitter.TwitterOAuth',
            'social_core.backends.github.GithubOAuth2',

            'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
        )

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'project_folder.wsgi.application'



# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),)
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

try:
    from project_folder.local_settings import *
except ImportError:
    print('local_settings error')
    pass

CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap4'

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'daily_brief_home'

LOGIN_URL = 'login'

SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_KEY = '****************'  # Removed for security purposes but there was a code
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SECRET = '***************'  # Removed for security purposes but there was a code


EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST_USER = os.environ['DB_USER']  
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = os.environ['DB_PASS']
```

project main folder local_settings.py

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
```

project main folder urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),

    path('', include('apps.daily_brief.urls')),

    path('', include('apps.users.urls')),

    path('', include('apps.crm.urls')),
]

# if settings.DEBUG: 
#     urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

users app admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Profile 

admin.site.register(Profile)
```

users app apps.py

```
from django.apps import AppConfig

class UsersConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'users'

    def ready(self):
        import users.signals
```

users app forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from .models import Profile  

class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):  
    email = forms.EmailField()  
    
    class Meta:  
        model = User  
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']  

class UserUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):  
    email = forms.EmailField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username','email']

class ProfileUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):  
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['image']
```

users app models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User  
from PIL import Image  

class Profile(models.Model):  
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)  
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')  

    def __str__(self):  
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'  

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):  
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)  

        img = Image.open(self.image.path)  
        if img.height > 300 or img.width > 300: 
            output_size = (300, 300) 
            img.thumbnail(output_size) 
            img.save(self.image.path)
```

users app signals.py

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save  
from django.contrib.auth.models import User  
from django.dispatch import receiver  
from .models import Profile  

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)  
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):  
    if created:  
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

users app urls.py

```
from django.urls import path, include
from .views import register, profile
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from django.conf import settings  
from django.conf.urls.static import static  
from django.views.static import serve  

urlpatterns = [
    path('register/', register, name='register'),
    path('profile/', profile, name='profile'),
    path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='users/login.html'), name='login'),
    path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(template_name='users/logout.html'), name='logout'),
    path('oauth/', include('social_django.urls', namespace='social')),
    path('password_reset/', auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(template_name='users/password_reset.html'), name='password_reset'), 
    path('password_reset/done', auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(template_name='users/password_reset_done.html'), name='password_reset_done'),
    path('password_reset_confirm/<uidb64>/<token>/', auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(template_name='users/password_reset_confirm.html'), name='password_reset_confirm'),
    path('password_reset_complete', auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(template_name='users/password_reset_complete.html'), name='password_reset_complete'),
]

if settings.DEBUG: 
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

users app views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
# from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib import messages
from .forms import UserRegisterForm, UserUpdateForm, ProfileUpdateForm
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)  
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save() 
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')  
            messages.success(request, f'Account created for {username}!') 
            return redirect('login') 
    else:
        form = UserRegisterForm()  
    return render(request, 'users/register.html', {'form': form}) 


@login_required  
def profile(request):  
    if request.method == 'POST':
        u_form = UserUpdateForm(request.POST,  instance=request.user)
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.user.profile)
        if u_form.is_valid() and p_form.is_valid():
            u_form.save()
            p_form.save()
            messages.success(request, f'Your account has been updated!')  
            return redirect('profile')  
    else:
        u_form = UserUpdateForm(instance=request.user)
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(instance=request.user.profile)
    context = {'u_form': u_form, 'p_form': p_form}  
    return render(request, 'users/profile.html', context)  


class SocialMediaLoginView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'users/login.html'
```

In projects main folder and users app init.py is emtpy
My directory mapping [Directory mapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gq38U.png)

Answer (score 0):

Somehow I sort it out; but I dont know the logic behind of it. I literraly coppied my two function from signals.py file into my models.py file with the releted imports and it's worked :)

There is the final models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User  
from PIL import Image  

from django.db.models.signals import post_save  
from django.dispatch import receiver  


class Profile(models.Model):  
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)  
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')  

    def __str__(self):  
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'  

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):  
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)  

        img = Image.open(self.image.path)  
        if img.height > 300 or img.width > 300: 
            output_size = (300, 300) 
            img.thumbnail(output_size) 
            img.save(self.image.path)
 

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)  
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):  
    if created:  
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```